# c# BouncyCastle decrypt byte array with a password

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, pgp, openpgp

I am trying to replicate the following javascript (which uses openpgp):

```
const encryptedMessage = await readMessage({
    binaryMessage: Uint8Array.from(encrypted_data.data), // parse encrypted bytes
});
try {
    const { data: decrypted } = await decrypt({
        message: encryptedMessage,
        passwords: [password.current], // decrypt with password
        format: "binary", // output as Uint8Array
    });

    console.log("decrypted:", decrypted); // Uint8Array([0x01, 0x01, 0x01])
    let decrypted_json: any = JSON.parse(Buffer.from(decrypted).toString("utf8"));
}
```

I've been trying to understand how to use bouncycastle to replicate these few lines in c# and have not been having much luck.. is that library just overkill for this application?

This JS function defaults to aes256, so maybe there is an easier way..

Thanks